Flask DEBUG logging not working with dictConfig root confirguration
I do not seem to be able to make logging work. The following does not print anything to console.
I have been digging into the official documentation, SO, and even Reddit... and nothing seems to work for me :/
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from logging.config import dictConfig
import urllib.request
import logging
import sys
import os

def create_app():
    
    # https://betterstack.com/community/guides/logging/how-to-start-logging-with-flask/
    dictConfig(
        {
            "version": 1,
            "formatters": {
                "default": {
                    "format": "[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s in %(module)s: %(message)s",
                }
            },
            "handlers": {
                "console": {
                    "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
                    "stream": "ext://sys.stdout",
                    "formatter": "default",
                }
            },
            "root": {"level": "DEBUG", "handlers": ["console"]},
        }
    )
    app = Flask(__name__)

    LOGGER = logging.getLogger("root")

    @app.get('/whatever')
    def view_zuerivelo_publibike() -> Flask.response_class:
        LOGGER.info('HELLO!') // nothing gets logged here

        # fetch raw XML
        try:
            response = urllib.request.urlopen(some_uri).read()
        except Exception as e:
            return jsonify({ 'message': e }), 500

        LOGGER.info(response) // nothing gets logged here
        
        return jsonify(response), 200
    
    return app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_app().run(debug=True, use_reloader=False)



Although you've configured the root logger, Flask uses its own logger by default. You can explicitly set app.logger to use your custom logger or configure both the root logger and the flask.app logger.
"loggers": {
            "flask.app": {"level": "DEBUG", "handlers": ["console"], "propagate": False},
        }

and then set LOGGER = logging.getLogger("flask.app") 
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from logging.config import dictConfig
import logging


def create_app():
    dictConfig(
        {
            "version": 1,
            "formatters": {
                "default": {
                    "format": "[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s in %(module)s: %(message)s",
                }
            },
            "handlers": {
                "console": {
                    "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
                    "stream": "ext://sys.stdout",
                    "formatter": "default",
                }
            },
            "root": {"level": "DEBUG", "handlers": ["console"]},
            "loggers": {
                "flask.app": {
                    "level": "DEBUG",
                    "handlers": ["console"],
                    "propagate": False,
                },
            },
        }
    )

    app = Flask(__name__)
    LOGGER = logging.getLogger("flask.app")

    @app.get("/whatever")
    def view_zuerivelo_publibike():
        LOGGER.info("HELLO!")
        try:
            some_uri = "http://example.com/data.xml"
            response = "Hello, World!"
        except Exception as e:
            LOGGER.error(f"Error fetching URI: {e}")
            return jsonify({"message": str(e)}), 500

        LOGGER.info(response)
        return jsonify(response), 200

    return app


if __name__ == "__main__":
    create_app().run(debug=True, use_reloader=False)


